# Python - scraping data with similar format

Tags: python, performance, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

my first time writing here, although i am spending enough time looking for answers.
A rather simple question where i hope someone can help!

I want to scrape some data from below url:
https://tracker.icon.foundation/addresses/1?count=100
https://tracker.icon.foundation/block/1

The website is dynamically updated, thus i had to use beautiful soup with Selenium.

I am trying to use the same code to scrape info (addresses in both cases), as it seems to me the structure is exactly the same in the two url's. I can scrape from the first one, but the second returns an empty list.. I have 2 questions:
a) Any idea why? :)
b) Performance is rather slow - any better way to do that?

Thanks!

The code I am using for the first url is the following.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="MYPATHFORWEBDRIVER")
driver.get('https://tracker.icon.foundation/addresses/1?count=100')
res = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

box = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-box'})

all_addresses = box.find_all('span', {'class': 'ellipsis'})
AddressList = []

for address in all_addresses:
    a_type = address.find('a', {'class': 'on'}).text
    AddressList.append(a_type)

print(AddressList)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the page is loaded dynamically. Issue here is that you get the html prior the html tree you are looking for being part of the DOM.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://tracker.icon.foundation/addresses/1?count=100')

# Wait until the element is loaded (found)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-box')))

#Parse the page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()
box = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-box'})


all_addresses = box.find_all('span', {'class': 'ellipsis'})
AddressList = []

for address in all_addresses:
    a_type = address.find('a', {'class': 'on'}).text
    AddressList.append(a_type)
print(AddressList)
```

Output:

```
['hxcd6f04b2a5184715ca89e523b6c823ceef2f9c3d', 'hx9f0c84a113881f0617172df6fc61a8278eb540f5', 'hx1729b35b690d51e9944b2e94075acff986ea0675', 'hx562dc1e2c7897432c298115bc7fbcc3b9d5df294', 'hx68646780e14ee9097085f7280ab137c3633b4b5f', 'hx0cc3a3d55ed55df7c8eee926a4fafb5412d0cca4', 'hx9d9ad1bc19319bd5cdb5516773c0e376db83b644', 'hxa9c54005bfa47bb8c3ff0d8adb5ddaac141556a3', 'hxc1481b2459afdbbde302ab528665b8603f7014dc', 'hx3f945d146a87552487ad70a050eebfa2564e8e5c', 'hx6b38701ddc411e6f4e84a04f6abade7661a207e2', 'hx7062a97bed64624846f3134fdab3fb856dce7075', 'hx8913f49afe7f01ff0d7318b98f7b4ae9d3cd0d61', 'hx980ab0c7473013f656339795a1c63bf44898ce95', 'hxbc2f530a7cb6170daae5876fd24d5d81170b93fe', 'hxc17ff524858dd51722367c5b04770936a78818de', 'hxfc7888bf63d45df125cf567fd8753c05facb3d12', 'hxd3b53e10d8c4c755879be09ff9ba975069664b7a', 'hxdf6bd350edae21f84e0a12392c17eac7e04817e7', 'hx9e19d60c9d6a0ecc2bcace688eff9053622c0c4c', 'hxa527f96d8b988a31083167f368105fc0f2ab1143', 'hx1000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'hx294c5d0699615fc8d92abfe464a2601612d11bf7', 'hxd42f6e3abfb7f5b14dbdafa34f03ffecf2a53a92', 'hxe322ab9b11b63c89b85b9bc7b23350b1d6604595', 'hx87b6da94535754c2baee9d69010eb1b91eaa4c37', 'hx58b2592941f61f97c7a8bed9f84c543f12099239', 'hx8d6aa6dce658688c76341b7f70a56dce5361e7ef', 'hx930bb66751f476babc2d49901cf77429c5cf05c1', 'hx39f2636582cee00b72586a2f74dc6028c0f0213f', 'hxd9fb974459fe46eb9d5a7c438f17ae6e75c0f2d1', 'hx49c5c7eead084999342dd6b0656bc98fa103b185', 'hx76dcc464a27d74ca7798dd789d2e1da8193219b4', 'hxc05ec08b6446a2a16b64eb19b96ea02225b840ab', 'hxe295a8dc5d6c29109bc402e59394d94cf600562e', 'hxf6f5f2583a0821f281fe7d35b013b9389daf2aaa', 'hxb6a65d0e7d5c1c0150310287e97c612a8ac825eb', 'hx6d14b2b77a9e73c5d5804d43c7e3c3416648ae3d', 'hxeb00139ddd1fa4507d3158e46e22c4ab7e8b9202', 'hx538de7e0fc0d312aa82549aa9e4daecc7fabcce9', 'hx6eb81220f547087b82e5a3de175a5dc0d854a3cd', 'hxc4193cda4a75526bf50896ec242d6713bb6b02a3', 'hx266c053380ad84224ea64ab4fa05541dccc56f5f', 'hx476455c56c64fea4f425bd62f0d2d3ab8cdcace0', 'hx85532472e789802a943bd34a8aeb86668bc23265', 'hx56ef2fa4ebd736c5565967197194da14d3af88ca', 'hx5d0409cabaacd0f1ef22d32f41a30649ee990103', 'hxbf90314546bbc3ed980454c9e2a9766160389302', 'hxe07878b53679ba1278d0aab1dac7646d8898d344', 'hx96505aac67c4f9033e4bac47397d760f121bcc44', 'hx18d14ad97ab2903dfc246ccc4e5631a3a1e13141', 'hx39f24d1d23b710b9d6ef6f56acfb3022deed8f4d', 'hxc574629fa3d1cc846611f1ab91d504ad7fc35413', 'hxd7a34c15c2345d9f0891545350181c7b162d9e08', 'hx314348ecbaf01ff6c65c2877a6c593a5facecb35', 'hx23cb1d823ef96ac22ae30c986a78bdbf3da976df', 'hx307c01535bfd1fb86b3b309925ae6970680eb30d', 'hx206846faa5ba46a3717e7349bff9c20d6fe1bba3', 'hx161665fb51075d37cee2c98c2eacbc94d207a58b', 'hxaf3a561e3888a2b497941e464f82fd4456db3ebf', 'hxa55446e81997c03ee856a58ee18432325a4ef924', 'hx6607ef84572ac9bdb1ebbcf49bd0cddaf8903b8e', 'hx37f86d0a4e1e2fada3ca724a401037c83e0a670e', 'hxc4bb0a9c4b3e9e5953262aa7cb940dbecb568ff6', 'hxc39a4c8438abbcb6b49de4691f07ee9b24968a1b', 'hxc35567f68c43bd98b020e5f0fab69ca21edb2726', 'hxc0fc3fca32bddba77f372c69c5998c1da81d531d', 'hx25c5dace83bceae42c11360a07c9e42a3b5c6122', 'hx387f3016ee2e5fb95f2feb5ba36b0578d5a4b8cf', 'hx94a7cd360a40cbf39e92ac91195c2ee3c81940a6', 'hx748717b9f846120033ba44e986722d82ef710afb', 'hxebfc6198ce53846b2e5d4ef31d6d13d0fa951c01', 'hx4602589eb91cf99b27296e5bd712387a23dd8ce5', 'hxa67e30ec59e73b9e15c7f2c4ddc42a13b44b2097', 'hx558b4cd8cd7c25fa25e3109414bb385e3c369660', 'hxad2bc6446ee3ae23228889d21f1871ed182ca2ca', 'hx777ee46b7b9d90a26388fbcdeafc742f5f217af7', 'hx10ed7a7065d920e146c86d3915491f5a67248647', 'hx33fc29d457e7815fe6c7cec4304500d5214fdac1', 'hx1494e29d38aea1a8e39fb40663c37f714bffb9df', 'hx9db3998119addefc2b34eaf408f27ab8103edaef', 'hxa91a8cd8141d192f78540d092d912456fb81d281', 'hx0b047c751658f7ce1b2595da34d57a0e7dad357d', 'hxc0b37fc42b52bf467720cf362c87c650ae3a7915', 'hx1216aa95cf2aea0a387b7c243412022f3d7cf29f', 'hx4c7c152410d4defd66da1d6c399c01de0bc295a5', 'hx4d83813703f81cdb85f952a1d1ee736faf732655', 'hx6d2240f9c5fd0db5df6977ee586c3d74e1b1e4aa', 'hxaafc8af9559d5d320745345ec006b0b2170194aa', 'hxabdde23cda5b425e71907515940a8f23e29a3134', 'hx6c22cdba886614d3173e3d2499dc1597bdb57f2c', 'hxd8ba6317da2eec0d9d7d1feed4c9c1f3cf358ae1', 'hxdd4bc4937923dc140adba57916e3559d039f4203', 'hx27664cffd284b8cf488eefb7880f55ce82f42297', 'hx8243caf740598c2b8d57c177adc999da68ea46bf', 'hx230fdd2eb239d5f590c7ff2d94a32b8899fc0628', 'hxd3f062437b70ab6d6a5f21b208ede64973f70567', 'hxc41d0b098fe9b86b241dfbfa9741f00975db2847', 'hxed97cf0deba62ffe843262f7f4596e155e8ea0b9', 'hx8d45deb8de633ca9d5de5fc5a64c51bccd8e9960']
```

Note you will need the following additional imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

For your other question about performance, you might use an headless browser which will speed things up a bit.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it didn't solve the issue on the second url and the list is still coming up empty (you applied the solution on the url that was functioning). I should have thought of the wait function, but i tried to apply it and somehow hit roadblocks.. Makes sense - the headless argument i also had tried but i was receiving an error - none has no object, most probably because i didn't have the wait function.. Nevertheless, the answer from @MendelG is better as it really solves any performance issue. I just need to get my head around it :)

Comment: Indeed if there is an API, request is a better option

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. However, we can get the data via sending a `GET` requests to

```
https://tracker.icon.foundation/v3/address/list?page=<PAGE NUM>&count=100
```

To get all the data from pages 1-100, we can use the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function

```
import requests

url = "https://tracker.icon.foundation/v3/address/list?page={}&count=100"

for page in range(1, 101):
    print("URL: ", url.format(page))
    response = requests.get(url.format(page)).json()
    print([data["address"] for data in response["data"]], "\n")
```

Output (partial):

```
URL:  https://tracker.icon.foundation/v3/address/list?page=1&count=100
['hxcd6f04b2a5184715ca89e523b6c823ceef2f9c3d', .... 'hx8d45deb8de633ca9d5de5fc5a64c51bccd8e9960'] 
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you; actually this is the kind of solution i was looking for. it is very effective and quick - no performance issues. Can u maybe help me apply it to the second URL to extract the From/To/Amount or any other field? Applying the same logic brings me an error.. (url1 = "https://tracker.icon.foundation/v3/block/list?page={}")....print([data["Amount"] for data in response["data"]], "\n") - or 'From' in the case of an address. I receive as key error the 'Amount' or 'From' etc..

Comment: PS i was trying to give you the credit but my reputation is still small and it says it won't show publicly..

Comment: Actually code is as follows: url1 = "https://tracker.icon.foundation/block/{}" .....             for i in range(1, 3):
    print("URL1: ", url1.format(i))
    response = requests.get(url1.format(i)).json()
    print([data["Amount"] for data in response["data"]], "\n")  ... but i get an error (expecting value) although the url printed is correct -- https://tracker.icon.foundation/block/1. Thanks!

Comment: actually i was wondering where you find the url of the json to build it accordingly.. So many questions - In the meantime, I research... i think my issue now is the url, which is incorrect - i am trying to find the 1st block and build it from there..

Comment: @st.g I'm not understanding your problem. You want to scrape the full table?

Comment: all clear, i wasn't sure how you had built the url from which you scraped the info from. I want to scrape different websites but found out you need to go to network and find the json file/url from there and scrape it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you mind if you clarify another question on your code (actually the last page, where you print the result). In another example, in the page, https://tracker.icon.foundation/v3/address/info?address=hx82b20bd58f7eef7df4d92ca6d03eefc0f759d77d the 'data' are not at the beginning which i assume is the reason i am not able to scrape the data. How would you build the string? Appreciate if you can show me with this example. And, what resources should i use to find out more about the construction of this?